No logro enviar el Select con sumit (`Warning: Undefined array key "posicion")
Bunas soy nuevo programando y tengo un gran problema no logro que la hora de enviar mi formulario envie el tipo select, todo lo demas funciona bien menos eso siempre me devuelve el mismo error. Gracias

*Warning: Undefined array key "posicion" in C:\xampp\htdocs\plantilla\forma.php on line 11

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'posicion' cannot be null in C:\xampp\htdocs\plantilla\forma.php:53 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\plantilla\forma.php(53): mysqli_stmt->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\plantilla\forma.php on line 53*
            </tr>   
            </tr>
                <td> 
                    <select class="seleccion" nane="posicion" required>
                    <option selected hidden value="">* SELECCIONA CARGO DESEADO</option> 
                        <option value="cajera">CAJERA</option>
                        <option value="customer">CURTOMER SERVICE</option>
                        <option value="astentem">ASISTENTE DE MERCADO</option>
                        <option value="pesador">PESADOR DE CARNE</option>
                        <option value="asociadon">ASOCIADO DE NEVERA</option>
                        <option value="chofer">CHOFER (CDL A o B)</option>
                        <option value="organizador">ORGANIZADOR DE CARRITOS</option>
                        <option value="prosesador">PROSESADOR DE ORDENES (Noche y Licencia Montacarga)</option>
                        <option value="limpieza">LIMPIEZA</option>
                        <option value="asistentew">ASISTNTE WAREHOUSE (Licencia Montacarga)</option>
                        <option value="tecnico">TECNICO EN REFIGERACION</option>
                        <option value="asistenteo">ASISTENTE DE OFICINA (Bilingue)</option>
                        <option value="cocinero">COCINERO</option>
                        <option value="empacador">EMPACADOR</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            

<?php
 
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$disponibilidad = $_POST['disponibilidad'];
$tiempo = $_POST['tiempo'];
$eleg = $_POST['eleg'];
$elegible = $_POST['elegible'];
$posicion = $_POST['posicion'];
$nombrec = $_POST['nombrec'];
$telefonoc = $_POST['telefonoc'];
$emailc = $_POST['emailc'];
$veterano = $_POST['veterano'];

if (!empty($fecha) ||
    !empty($nombre) ||
    !empty($email) ||
    !empty($telefono) ||
    !empty($disponibilidad) ||
    !empty($tiempo) ||
    !empty($eleg) ||
    !empty($elegible) ||
    !empty($posicion) ||
    !empty($nombrec) ||
    !empty($telefonoc) ||
    !empty($emailc) ||
    !empty($veterano) 
 ) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "Chsj*2020";
    $dbname = "formulario";

    $conn = new mysqli ($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die('connect error('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else{
        $SELECT = "SELECT telefono from aplicacion where telefono = ? limit 1";
        $INSERT = "INSERT INTO aplicacion (fecha,nombre,email,telefono,disponibilidad,tiempo,eleg,elegible,posicion,nombrec,telefonoc,emailc,veterano) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $telefono);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($telefono);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;
        if ($rnum == 0) {
            $stmt->close();
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
            $stmt->bind_param("sssisssssssss", $fecha, $nombre, $email, $telefono, $disponibilidad, $tiempo, $eleg, $elegible, $posicion, $nombrec, $telefonoc, $emailc, $veterano);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "REGISTRO COMPLETADO.";
        } else {
            "Alquien resgistro ese telefono";
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close(); 

}
else{
    echo "Todos los datos son OBLIGATORIOS";
    die();
}

?>


Tienes un typo en el input, nane deberia ser name

gracias pro su ayuda
